# Why I can't run steam on Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04, steam

I've installed it already.
but when I run steam it shows:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1

Fatal Error:Failed to load steamui.so
```

My Ubuntu version is 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you have your proprietary drivers installed? P.S. Steam supports 12.04LTS and up.

Comment: Exactly. Steam supports 12.04 and newer versions of Ubuntu. Also Ubuntu 10.04 will reach EOL in 1-2 months. (April). Consider to upgrade (or fresh install) to a newer and supported version such as Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 10.04 is not officially supported by Valve.**
Please see this Wiki-page for system requirements [Valve Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve)

It is not advised that you run Steam on your version of Ubuntu, however if you want to try it anyways the solution to your problem might be installing 32-bit compatibility libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

You should also make sure you have either ATI or NVIDIA proprietary drivers installed
(depending on your graphics card)  or you are using the [x-swat repository](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates)
if you're on an Intel HD4000 chip.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

**Even if this gets Steam to work prepare to run into errors because of graphics driver incompatibility and other problems.**

Please don't file bug reports on any problems occuring while using Steam with Ubuntu 10.04 because as stated by ['NikTh'](https://askubuntu.com/users/95393/nikth) it'll reach its 'End Of Life' with the release of Ubuntu 13.04 in April this year.